# How to extend an Angular factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I have a data services file that I want to break up into smaller modules/pieces. Currently, the code is something like the following:

```
angular
    .module('myapp')
    .factory('DataService', DataService)

DataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function DataService($http) {
    var service = {
        methodOne: methodOne,
        methodTwo: methodTwo,
        methodThree: methodThree
    };
    return service;
}
```

What I want to do: Separate this one file into three other files and put each of the methods in their own files. For example, there is a common DataService file and 3 others that contain the actual implementation of the 3 methods. I'm trying to create different factories like below, but I'm not sure if this is correct. I can't get it to work when calling it

```
angular
    .module('myapp')
    .factory('DataService', DataService)

DataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function DataService($http) {
    var service = {}; //creating empty object
    return service;
}


//File 1
angular
    .module('myapp')
    .factory('dataServiceOne', function(DataService){
        var extended = angular.extend(DataService, {})
        extended.methodOne = function() {
            console.log('working method one')
        }
        return extended;
    });

//File 2
angular
    .module('myapp')
    .factory('dataServiceTwo', function(DataService){
        var extended = angular.extend(DataService, {})
        extended.methodOne = function() {
            console.log('working method two')
        }
        return extended;
    });

//File 3
angular
    .module('myapp')
    .factory('dataServiceThree', function(DataService){
        var extended = angular.extend(DataService, {})
        extended.methodOne = function() {
            console.log('working method three')
        }
        return extended;
    });
```

Then calling it elsewhere in the app. Gives me an error saying methodOne is not a function.

```
...
DataService.methodOne() //this is implementation
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with the code is `dataServiceOne`, `dataServiceTwo` and `dataServiceThree` factories are not been initialized if you dont inject them DataService will not extend, I have created a fiddle which creates a wrapper service to do so,

So instead of injecting DataService, you may inject WrapperService and it will in turn extend DataService (Not sure if solves your purpose)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/madhu_ranjan/tjh8xh6z/)

```
 //File 4
 angular
   .module('myapp')
   .factory('WrapperService', function(dataServiceOne, dataServiceTwo,    dataServiceThree, DataService) {
       return DataService
   });

 angular
  .module('myapp')
    .controller("MYController", ["$scope", "WrapperService",    function($scope, DataService) {
      DataService.methodOne();
      DataService.methodTwo();
      DataService.methodThree();
   }]);
```

Comment: I notice in the MYController you inject "WrapperService" but then you use DataService in the arguments. Did you mean WrapperService instead of DataService in the argument?

Comment: Nope! If you see in Wrapperservice i am returning object of DataService, and while injecting i have just renamed WrapperService to DataService, you may call what ever u want :)

Comment: I have done that but I get an error saying that methodOne is not a function when I try to use DataService.methodOne() inside a directive. I get this for all of the methods...I have injected all of the necessary components.

Comment: have you looked into the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/madhu_ranjan/tjh8xh6z/), can you create one Fiddle and share, so that i may look into it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? Inheritance in AngularJS

```
// Inject your factories in your controller(s)
var module = angular.module();
module.controller('yourController', ['$scope', 'DataServiceOne', 'DataServiceTwo', 'DataServiceThree', 
function($scope, DataServiceOne, DataServiceTwo, DataServiceThree) {
    // use these factories
}
]);


module.factory('DataService', function ($q, $http) {
   return {
      //public API
   };
});

module.factory('DataServiceOne', function (DataService, $sce) {
   var child = Object.create(DataService);
   child.methodOne = function () {
     //extending the parent
     console.log('working method one');
   };
   return child;
});

module.factory('DataServiceTwo', function (DataService, $sce) {
   var child = Object.create(DataService);
   child.methodOne = function () {
      //extending the parent
      console.log('working method two');
   };
   return child;
});

module.factory('DataServiceThree', function (DataService, $sce) {
   var child = Object.create(DataService);
   child.methodOne = function () {
      //extending the parent
      console.log('working method three');
   };
   return child;
});
```

Comment: Yes, something like this, however, how do I implement it. Lets say I want to cale methodOne from DataService? DataService.methodOne?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please have a look. You may inject these child factories into your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamic methods to any object just by assigning the functions to a property of the object. I used controllers here so it's easy to see, but the concept is the same.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
        <div>{{ctrl.hello}}</div>
        <div>{{ctrl.method1()}}</div>
        <div>{{ctrl.method2()}}</div>
        <div>{{ctrl.method3()}}</div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js "></script>
    <script src="dynamicmethods.js"></script>
        <script>
        angular.module('app', []).controller("myController",myController);

        function  myController($scope){
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.hello ="Hello"
            decorate() ;

            function decorate() {
                ctrl.method1 = method1
                ctrl.method2 = method2
                ctrl.method3 = method3
            }    

        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

dynamicmethods.js

```
function method1() {
    return "I'm one"
}

function method2() {
    return "I'm two"
};

function method3() {
    return "I'm three"
}
```

Comment: This is quite different from what I'm trying to achieve though. I want to have different factories for the functions that I specified. That's the direction I'm trying to go in

Comment: I guess I don't follow the question then. From what I can tell, you're basically trying to add methods to the factories dynamically, but it looks like you're way overcomplicating it to me. Basically as long as those functions are in memory you can assign them as members to any object you like. I have a generic service that I use for all of my oData sources that I do something quite similar with.

Comment: Well if I do that and the method1 is in my factory and the actual method1 definition is in another file, I get the error "ReferenceError: method1 is not defined"

Comment: Did you load the separate Javascript file somewhere? I just changed the code in my answer to reference functions from a separate file and it still works.